# JSON to Array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, json

Hi how to Parse JSON string using JQuery or Javascript??

I have the JSON string like below format.

```
var JSON = "{ "UserID":"1","ClientID":"1","UserName":"User1"}"
```

I wanna to parse this JSON string. so that i can get

```
var UserID = 1
var ClientID = 1
UserName = User1
```

Can anybody help me out..

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: [Parse the JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) into a JavaScript object and extract the desired data. Read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) if you don't know how to access properties of objects (JavaScript basics).

Comment: I tried var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);  It showing Object expected. But i tried with double quotes.

Comment: this is working obj = JSON.parse(json); Thank you Felix and you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be wary of unescaped quotation marks in that string. I changed the outer quotes to single quotes.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "UserID":"1","ClientID":"1","UserName":"User1"}')

var UserID = obj.UserID 
var ClientID = obj.ClientID
var UserName = obj.UserName
```

Comment: I tried this. But i am getting error as Object does not support this property or method.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you execute the JSON variable you have there, should give you a syntax error because you need to escape the double quotes, such as:

```
var JSON = "{ \"UserID\":\"1\",\"ClientID\":\"1\",\"UserName\":\"User1\"}";
```

or simply use single quotes to create the string

```
var JSON = '{ "UserID":"1","ClientID":"1","UserName":"User1"}';
```

Then you can just parse it using [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
obj.UserID == 1; // true
```

Comment: I tried this. But i am getting error as Object does not support this property or method.